# use rest api to search a specific folder inside of shared documents

Tags: search, api

I have added to the HelloWorld web part starting example to include a search, and I have successfully limited it to my site instead of the entire tenant.

```
const here = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${here}/_api/search/query?querytext='${toSearchFor} IsDocument:true Site:${here}'
    &expand=Files/ListItemAllFields
    &rowLimit=20`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: [
          ['accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose'],
          ['odata-version', '']
        ]
      })
     .then((res: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{}> => {
        return res.json();
     })
```

This works and only searches my site.  Now I'm trying to limit it further by setting the path to a folder 'Documentation' inside of Shared Documents.

```
const searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared%20Documents/Documentaion";
this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${here}/_api/search/query?querytext='${toSearchFor} IsDocument:true Site:${searchTarget}'
```

also tried

```
searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared Documents/Documentaion";
searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared\ Documents/Documentaion";
searchTarget = "(https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared Documents/Documentaion)";
searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared%20Documents/Documentaion";
searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared+Documents/Documentaion";
```

But anything other than 'this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl' returns 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Path managed property instead, like:

```
const searchTarget = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/name/Shared%20Documents/Documentaion*";
this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${here}/_api/search/query?querytext='${toSearchFor} IsDocument:true path:${searchTarget}'
```

Note the asterix at the end of searchTarget to make it do prefix matching

Comment: this also got 0 results.